# RequireJS and Angular, adding library with angularJS dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, dependencies

For my project I am using **AngularJS** and **RequireJS**. I just ran into a problem and I don't know how to fix it.

---

**The problem**

I am inporting an AngularJS library for my menu (**AngularJS Pageslide directive**). This library uses AngularJS module for creating a module. Due to RequireJS and manually bootstrapping Angular is not yet available when instantiating this class. Due to this I cannot use the module (it is never defined). How should I add this library, so that I can use it?

---

**Main.js**

For requireJS I am using a main.js. The part for this library is as follows:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'modules',
    paths: {       
        //MENU
        'angular-pageslide': '../lib/angular-pageslide-directive',     
    },   
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Load all app components (bootstrap angular)
function onDeviceReady() {
    requirejs([       
        'angular-pageslide'        
    ], function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });
```

But this gives me the error '`Angular is undefined`'.

I have also tried:

```
 paths: {       
        'angular-pageslide': '../lib/angular-pageslide-directive'
    },
    shim: {        
        'angular-pageslide': {deps: ['angular']},      
    }
```

But with this code I don't know how to include it in my controller as a dependency. (javascript doesn't like me using 'angular-pageslide' as a dependency. Gives type errors, `Unexpected '-'`.)

---

**Anyone knows what the best solution for this problem is?**

Comment: are you using ui-router ?

Comment: @ngLover no, I am using $routeProvider. (angular-route)